# Compiling pdfs from LaTeX in emacs

Tags: pdf, emacs, latex

I'm using `auctex` in Emacs, and call `C-c C-c`. This compiles me a DVI, which looks great, and is exactly right, and also a PDF which... doesn't - it essentially has none of my text or formatting, and is just a plaintext version of my preamble. After I run `dvipdfm` from my command line on the DVI file, I get the PDF that I want, but I'd rather not have to do a compilation *twice*. Is there a way to make Emacs do this part as well?

Comment: Have you tried using either `(TeX-global-PDF-mode t)` or this:  `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (setq TeX-PDF-mode t) (setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t) (setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex) ))`.  Essentially, the variable `TeX-PDF-mode` being set to `t` tells AUCTeX to create a `*.pdf` file.

Comment: Here is a link to what my setup looks like for OSX and Windows:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22746845/2112489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `pdflatex` at compilation time in Emacs.